# Gmail Error : 'cyk: Failed to create local attachment' when adding image attachment

Tags: android, android-studio, gmail

im my app people can select up to 6 images, at the end of the app i want to add these images to an email to the appropriate email adress.

the system works but when i added :

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

gmail gives this error: 'cyk: Failed to create local attachment'

after some testing i found out this is caused by not all images always being there,
if i add all images it only sends the last one.

here is the code:

```
 public void SendButtonDown(View v){
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Uri MAIL_IMAGES_URI = Uri.parse("file://"+MAIL_IMAGES);
    Uri MAIL_IMAGES_URI2 = Uri.parse("file://"+MAIL_IMAGES2);
    Uri MAIL_IMAGES_URI3 = Uri.parse("file://"+MAIL_IMAGES3);
    Uri MAIL_IMAGES_URI4 = Uri.parse("file://"+MAIL_IMAGES4);
    Uri MAIL_IMAGES_URI5 = Uri.parse("file://"+MAIL_IMAGES5);
    Uri MAIL_IMAGES_URI6 = Uri.parse("file://"+MAIL_IMAGES6);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL   , new String[]{"testmail@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , "Subject");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT    , textVar);
    i.setType("application/image");


    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  , MAIL_IMAGES_URI);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  , MAIL_IMAGES_URI2);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  , MAIL_IMAGES_URI3);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  , MAIL_IMAGES_URI4);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  , MAIL_IMAGES_URI5);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  , MAIL_IMAGES_URI6);


    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
        Toast.makeText(AanbiedenStap3.this, "no email installed", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    finish();
}
}
```

Here is the Full Logcat:

```
09-23 15:16:44.065 11793-11793/? E/Gmail: Error adding attachment
                                      cyk: Failed to create local attachment
                                          at cyl.a(SourceFile:344)
                                          at cfe.a(SourceFile:3353)
                                          at cfn.run(SourceFile:6191)
                                          at cfe.a(SourceFile:19310)
                                          at cfe.a(SourceFile:1198)
                                          at cfe.C(SourceFile:1307)
                                          at cfe.onCreate(SourceFile:8505)
                                          at com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail.onCreate(SourceFile:201)
                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes of course it sends only the last one. You over write the others yourself. There can only be one  `i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  ,.....);`.

Comment: Then how do i send multiple images in a single email?

Comment: Attaching more files has to be done different. I wonder why you dont google a bit to find how that has to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the app,
in case you also ran into this problem here is the fix:

```
public void SendButtonDown(View v){
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    if(MAIL_IMAGES != null) {
        filePaths.add(MAIL_IMAGES);
    }
    if(MAIL_IMAGES2 != null) {
        filePaths.add(MAIL_IMAGES2);
    }
    if(MAIL_IMAGES3 != null) {
        filePaths.add(MAIL_IMAGES3);
    }
    if(MAIL_IMAGES4 != null) {
        filePaths.add(MAIL_IMAGES4);
    }
    if(MAIL_IMAGES5 != null) {
        filePaths.add(MAIL_IMAGES5);
    }
    if(MAIL_IMAGES6 != null) {
        filePaths.add(MAIL_IMAGES6);
    }

    final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL   , new String[]{"testmail@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT , "subject");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT    , data);

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String file : filePaths){
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }
    i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));

    finish();
}
}
```